# drag and drop in android

Tags: android

I have to develop a shuffled image puzzle. How to implement drag and drop for that?

Comment: You should start to accept some answers. Now.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, create a  [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout) and implement a basic part and 
 you can find documentation for the Drag and Drop implementations in Android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to listen in on the motion events of your objects and handle the events when the dragged object enters a target area.

I made a simple example using Monodroid. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/rondelrosario/DragAndDrop).