# How to create android custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a picture in my app that can be split into 6 x 6 or 5 x 5 or 4 x 4 grib depending on the users selection.

Can someone tell me how to create a tile view that will house the pieces, and the user should be able to move the pieces around the view.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229461/drag-and-drop-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out the [Drag and Drop Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/DragAndDropDemo.html) in API Demos.

As far as the grid, your best bet is probably TableLayout, as GridView has a one-dimensional view of your data.

Answer (score 0):

take a frame layout and oweride the onDraw method